# Attaching another view to the same "files owner"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am not sure how to ask this, or if it is already answered, but I cannot find anything specific. Basically, what I want to do is have a view/xib that has the same "Files owner" information as another view. The purpose of this would be to have an ipad view, much like the viewCOntroller_iphone/viewcontroller_ipad that one gets when using a universal app. How do I link this though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just select the particular XIB, assign its custom class to the similar class u use, u can find it in identity inspector