# Customizing UISearchbar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uisearchbar

Is it possible to customize UISearchBar which is inside UITableView, I want to remove Cancel button and put two other buttons instead of cancel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UISearchBar is not very customizable. You can see [in its documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678620/can-i-use-two-xibs-with-one-viewcontroller-re-porting-to-iphone-5?rq=1) the kinds of things which you can customize. You can hide the cancel button, but you can't add your own arbitrary buttons.

You might want to replace it with a UITextField and your own buttons, which will give you lots of flexibility, but will require more work to re-implement the UISearchBar's built-in behaviour.