# How can I dynamically modify a subview from another view?

Tags: cocoa

Let me explain my problem in the context of the program I'm working with. This program consists of one main window which has an NSOutlineView and an NSTabView. The NSTabViewItems (and their corresponding subview) are added dynamically at runtime (using Cmd+T). The aforementioned subview is part of a separate XIB file; the subview consists of various simple input controls. All of this works as I've just described.

I want the NSOutlineView to offer context menus for the various items it is displaying which may manipulate some of the controls within the currently active NSTabViewItem's subview.

The most obvious way that I see to do this is (this is just a simplified example, not my actual code):

**NSOutlineViewSubclass.h**

```
@interface ... : NSOutlineView
    @property (weak) IBOutlet NSTabView *tabView;
@end
```

**NSOutlineViewSubclass.m**

```
@implementation ...
    @synthesize tabView;

    - (void)foo
    {
        NSTabViewItem *currentTab = [tabView selectedTabViewItem];
        TabViewSubView *tabViewSubView = [currentTab view];

        //
        //Manipulate subview controls here
        //
    }

@end
```

This seems like it violates the MVC paradigm, since I am manipulating data directly in the view (in this case, NSOutlineViewSubclass), rather than going through a controller. But, for now, the only time I use the NSOutlineViewSubclassViewController is to spawn a new view for a new tab in the first place. My NSOutlineViewSubclass doesn't even know about it's NSOutlineViewSubclassViewController. Did I miss a step here in connecting these two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing something very important! I hadn't been taking advantage of the very important File's Owner within my XIB file. This gives me the ability to link between two XIBs and include a View Controller property.

I figured my answer out entirely from the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678620/can-i-use-two-xibs-with-one-viewcontroller-re-porting-to-iphone-5) (written, similarly, by it's asker Dale Dietrich).